# Exporting large list of dataframes to csv after split

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, split

I am creating a script that will split a dataframe into groups based on the column "participant id" and export those dataframes as csvs. Right now, I am working with a dataframe that only has 7 participant ids, but the script will be used for a csv with hundreds of participants.

First, here is a list of dataframes:

```
participant_id <- c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4")

text <- c("Message1","Message1","Message1",
 "Message2", "Message2", "Message2", 
 "Message3", "Message3", "Message3", 
 "Message4", "Message4", "Message4")

df <- data.frame(participant_id, text)

df_list <- split(df, df$participant_id)
```

Then I clean each dataframe in the list using a function I wrote called clean_log (the dataframe contains texting logs):

```
df_list <- lapply(df_list, clean_log)
```

I want to write each dataframe in this list to a csv, but the dataframes need to be saved as objects first. I tried naming them:

```
names <- c()

for (i in 1:length(df_list)) {
  names <- c(names, paste0("df", i))
}

names(df_list) <- names
```

Then I tried exporting the dataframes in a for loop but got the error "Error in get(names[i]) : object 'df1' not found:

```
for (i in 1:length(names)) {
  write.csv(get(names[i]),
            paste0(path, names[i], ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
}
```

I know I could simply write

```
df1 <- df_list[1]
df2 <- df_list[2]
...
```

To name each dataframe, but this isn't going to work when there are hundreds of dataframes to export. Has anyone run into an issue like this or have any advice?

Comment: Yes, this is a very solvable problem.  Please read this and provide at least an example of df_list. Also, do you need all these csv?  Can you keep the main file and split as needed? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I just updated the code to hopefully follow those guidelines, let me know how it looks! I need to export each as an individual csv for upload to google drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `get` here, and in general using `get` is a bad practice.

Your object `df_list` is a list of data frames. The first argument to `write.csv` should be the data frame you want to save. So you can write your loop as:

```r
paths = paste0(path, names, ".csv")
for (i in seq_along(df_list)) {
  write.csv(df_list[[i]], paths[i], row.names = FALSE)
}
```

I lifted the `paste0` call out of the loop because it's more efficient and idiomatic to use vectorization to create the file paths.

Comment: You're welcome. In that case, please accept the answer so others know this question is resolved.

Comment: Yes the [[ ]] is key.  Useful to remember in many situations.

Comment: Why using `get` in general is a bad practice?

Comment: The `get` function gets a variable by name, but it is clearer to do that by... just typing the variable's name. I also frequently see people using `get` because they haven't fully internalized when and how to use (named) lists, as in this question. There really aren't many compelling cases for using `get` in day-to-day programming. Its main use case is for working with environments, a specific type of R object.

Comment: Does anyone know how to export html or pdf files in this way instead of csv? Trying to format the csvs to be easier to read.

Comment: @lizronan22 Use the **rmarkdown** package or something similar. If you need further help, make a new question.